# Make the banner image scale proportionately with the available space in the viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a banner 900px width and 150px height, if I make the screen smaller then 900px using google chrome, I want it to adjust automatically, like scaling proportionately.
This is the code I am using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> .........some other code......

.banner {
  background: silver;
  padding: 20px 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

What would be the suggestions to achieve what I am seeking?

Answer (score 0):

What does it do right now?

Try: width: 100%; max-width: 900px

Comment: The whole lay out scales, even the silver background, but the photo stays the same width and doesn't scale at all, so it makes the whole thing zoom out. The text gets smaller like if it were zoomed out and etc. I want the photo scale accordingly to length of the whole silver background and left and right lines of borders (by borders I mean whole content's lay out)

Comment: img.banner {   width: 100%; max-width: 900px }

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code demonstrated below. Initially the banner is set to width of 900px and height (you can tweak it around to your needs). When the screen size reaches 900px, you can change the width of the banner with a relative value in percentage (%) or vw (view-width) like shown below. Hope, it helps.
Example code below:

```css
#banner{
width:900px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #banner {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="banner" src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/557d279498d303f3206fae0af97a62f3625ebf4e/c3c0d/images/header/leargas-banner-900px.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was referring only to .banner, it was unclear in instructions.
When I wrote
`.banner img {max-width: 100%}` it worked. and deleted `overflow` with `maxwidth` in `.banner`.